# OWL API: Good substitution for isSubclassOf method

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

Hello,

I am using the Java OWL API (version 5) and want to check if a class is a subclass of another class. Right now I am doing this by getting all superclasses of the intended subclass and check if this list contains the intended superclass. This approach works, but I need to do this for a lot if classes and if my ontology gets bigger, it's not really efficient.

It seems that there was an isSubclassOf(.., ..) method in OWLClassReasoner in previous releases of the OWL API. But in the current version both aren't present anymore.

Am I overlooking something and if not, is there a more efficient method to accomplish this task?

Comment: I don't know about 'isSubClassOf()' but there are  'getSubClasses()' & 'getSuperClasses()' that should do the job.  NB, right now your method is not complet because it use a sub-part of owl2 expressivity; If it is what you want, then it may be possible to have something faster than a DL-reasoner in your specific case. What do you really need ?

Comment: The correct and also common way is to use the method `OWLReasoner::isEntailed()` with the corresponding axiom as argument, i.e. in your case the SubClassOf axiom.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you, this is what I meant. Is this
`OWLSubClassOfAxiom subClassOfAxiom = dataFactory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(subClass, superClass);
reasoner.isEntailed(subClassOfAxiom);`
the right way to do it or can I create the axiom otherwise?

Comment: No, that's the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OWLClassReasoner` is an OWLAPI 2 class - last release for OWLAPI 2 was around 2009, I believe, so it's fair to say that code is obsolete.

With a real reasoner (i.e., one of HermiT or Openllet for OWLAPI 5 - they can be found on Maven Central) you can use the following code:

```
OWLReasoner reasoner = ...
OWLClass a = ...
OWLClass b = ...
boolean bIsSuperclass = reasoner.getSuperClasses(a, false).containsEntity(b);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am doing now. I just thought there is a more efficient to do this with a reasoner.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Computing the class hierarchy is done once by the reasoner, at latest once you call a query which needs the inferred hierarchy to be sound and complete. Otherwise, use the entailment check that I suggested. If you're talking about convenience, feel free to write your own method that wraps the code.

Comment: I searched for a more efficient method because I think my solution isn't efficient. I get all the superclasses of one class (which, depending on the ontology, can be quite big), put them in a list and check if that list contains the class that should be the superclass.
The `isSubClassOf(.., ..)` method did exactly what I needed, but it obsolete. So I was wondering if there is a proper replacement. You mentioned that your suggested method is the correct way to do it, so I assume this is the replacement I was looking for.
Thank you again!

Comment: If you need to do this for a small number of classes, the effort of looking through the collection (it's a set in the nodeset class) will be minimal compared to the cost of reasoning.

Comment: So what does fall under "reasoning" and what doesn't? Isn't `reasoner.getSuperClasses(a, false)` also reasoning? And yes, your approach may be minimal effort for a small number of classes, but both methods are relatively fast for a small number of classes. The question is, which approach is better for a large number of classes.

Comment: Reasoner.getSuperClasses() requires reasoning. What is the use case for looking up the superclasses of a large number of classes? It might be that you can use the fact that NodeSet is a set of Nodes, each node contains equivalent classes. You could reduce the number of calls using that information (all classes from the same node will give you the same results in this scenario).

Comment: The requirement isn't looking up a large number of classes. It is checking if a known class is or isn't a subclass of another known class. That needs to be done a lot of times for varying subclasses. You can imagine my ontology as a topic map and I want to check if a certain word, which is represented by a class in the ontology, is a subclass over another class, which represents some higher-level topic, to find out if it belongs to this main topic.